# ASP.NET global Application_Error event handler never gets invoked

Tags: asp.net, web-config, global-asax, custom-errors

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms application that logs unhandled exceptions in the Application_Error event handler in the Globas.asax file. This was working fine for some time, but due to an unknown change it stopped working. The method never gets called when an unhandled exception occurs.

The relevant part in the Web.Config file looks like this:

```
 <customErrors mode="Off" />
```

The handler method is:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            Logging.Logger.ServerLog_AddLogEntry(Logging.Logger.ServerLogEntryCategories.Debug, "Unhandled exception caught in global Application_Error(). User: " + Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name + ". The details should follow now...");

            // Get the exception object.
            Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();

            if (exc != null && exc is HttpUnhandledException)
                exc = exc.InnerException;
            else
            {
                if (Context != null && Context.AllErrors.Length > 0)
                {
                    string errors = string.Join(Environment.NewLine + "Exception: ", Context.AllErrors.Select(ae => ae.ToString()));
                    exc = new Exception("AllErrors: " + errors);
                }
            }

            if (exc != null)
                Logging.Logger.ServerLog_AddLogEntry(Logging.Logger.ServerLogEntryCategories.Error, "Unhandled exception caught in global Application_Error(). User: " + Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name + "." + Environment.NewLine + "Page: " + Request.Url.ToString(), exc);
            else
                Logging.Logger.ServerLog_AddLogEntry(Logging.Logger.ServerLogEntryCategories.Error, "Unhandled exception caught in global Application_Error(). No Exception available. User: " + Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name + "." + Environment.NewLine + "Page: " + Request.Url.ToString(), null);

            Server.ClearError();

            Server.Transfer("~/Error.aspx");
}
```

Even the first Logger method never gets executed. However, the user does get transferred to the Error.aspx page somehow.
Please note that this behavior only happens on the live server, but not when debugging locally.
I have verified that neither the Web.config nor the machine.config contain "retail=true" which would explain this behavior. 
Does anyone know what else could cause this?

Comment: Are you sure an unhandled exception is occurring? How are you creating this?

Comment: I have a test method with throw new Exception(). Apart fomr that, unhandled exceptions are frequently occuring throughout the application and none of them ever gets logged.

Comment: Fair enough. I will recommend you read through this documentation to be sure you are not missing anything - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417(v=vs.140).aspx